# Show that a function $f(x,y) = \phi(x) + \psi(y)$ is monotonically decreasing if and only if $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(y)$ are decreasing.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have come to a problem in a multivariate calculus book that I'm having trouble solving.

Let $I$ and $J$ be two non-empty intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. Given any
$\phi : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\psi : J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, define
$f,g : I \times J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y) := \phi(x) + \psi(y)$ and
$g(x,y) := \phi(x)\psi(y)$.

The problem asks the reader to prove that $f$ is monotonically decreasing on $I \times J$
if and only if $\phi$ is decreasing on $I$ and $\psi$ is decreasing on $J$.

Here $f$ is defined as monotonically decreasing on $I \times J$ if for all
$(x_{1},y_{1}),(x_{2},y_{2}) \in I \times J$ we have :
\begin{equation}
(x_{1},y_{1}) \leq (x_{2},y_{2}) \Rightarrow f(x_{1},y_{1}) \geq f(x_{2},y_{2})
\end{equation}
Where here $\leq$ is a partial order on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ s.t. :
\begin{equation}
(x_{1},y_{1}) \leq (x_{2},y_{2}) \Leftrightarrow x_{1} \leq x_{2} \text{ and } y_{1} \leq y_{2}
\end{equation}

Can someone help solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Let first $\phi, \psi$ be decreasing and $(x_1,y_1)\leq (x_2,y_2)$. Then $x_1\leq x_2$ and $y_1\leq y_2$. Thus $\phi(x_1)\geq\phi(x_2)$ and $\psi(y_1)\geq\psi(y_2)$ implying $\phi(x_1)+\psi(y_1)\geq \phi(x_2)+\psi(y_2)$ or $f(x_{1},y_{1}) \geq f(x_{2},y_{2})$.

Now let $x_1\leq x_2$ and choose $y\in J$. Then $f(x_{1},y) \geq f(x_{2},y)$. That is $\phi(x_1)+\psi(y)\geq \phi(x_2)+\psi(y)$. So $\phi(x_1)+\geq \phi(x_2)$ as desired. For $\psi$ the same idea works.